# Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'Selector'(after converting swift to swift 3)

Tags: swift, xcode

The error is coming in third line of code(after converting swift to swift3)

```
// Retrieve Value using User Defaults
if let date = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Current-Date") as? Date { 
    datePicker.setDate(date, animated: true)
}
datePicker.addTarget(self, action:nil, for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

Comment: set a selector/function to be called when the date picker value changes

Comment: What's hard to understand about the error message? You cannot say `action:nil`. Don't say it.

Comment: What's the point of calling `addTarget` with no action? If you don't want an action called, don't use `addTarget`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message really tells you all you need to know: you cannot pass `nil` as the value for the `action` parameter. Pass a valid Selector.

Answer (score 0):

The selector in `addTarget` isn't optional.
Here is the default definition for any UIControl :

```
// the action cannot be NULL. Note that the target is not retained.
open func addTarget(_ target: Any?, action: Selector, for controlEvents: UIControlEvents)
```

As you can see the `action` is a `Selector` not a `Selector?`, so you can't pass `nil`.